# Keep-together on topic level

Tags: xsl-fo, dita-ot

I am customizing the pdf2 plugin for dita-ot 2.4. My formatter is FOP.

I want to make my plugin prefer page breaks between topics. Hence, I tried adding the following attributes in the "topic" attribute set;

- "keep-together.within-page" with a value (20)
- "keep-with-previous.within page" set to auto (to override any other settings)

When I look at topic.fo it seems that it is only applied to "empty" topicrefs (headings without body text) without href attribute, but that may contain other topicrefs.

Example:

**Section 1**

Some body text...

**Section 2**

**Section 2.1**

Some more body text...

In this example, the wanted attributes are only found on the first fo:block of Section 2.

I have a number of "keep-with-previous.within page" with values lower than 20 on elements such as tables, figures, body text of different levels.

I just want to ask if there is a simple solution to my struggles. it would be nice to set these attributes on topic level as a start and not only try to "glue" the different parts together.

Best Regards,
Fredrik

Comment: Hopefully you're using '.', not ':'?  That is, using "keep-together.within-page" and "keep-with-previous.within page", not "keep-together:within-page" and "keep-with-previous:within page".  See, e.g., https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#datatype

Comment: What formatter are you using? You might be using some features not all formatters support.

Comment: I don't know why I wrote ":". I am using ".". The formatter is FOP. Thanks!

Comment: Since the additional attributes appear in only some of the expected places in the FO, this looks more like it's a problem with the pdf2 and/or dita-ot 2.4 XSLT.

Comment: @Tony: Well, I was thinking that I might have the _wrong_ expectations on the `topic` attribute-set. Perhaps I should use another set to get at the topics with actual content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the concept attribute set instead and it worked very well. Probably because all my topics are of the Concept type;) If you are using other topics, you should use the corresponding attribute-sets to get the same effect. Here's my final overriding customization of **commons-attr.xsl**:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="concept">
    <xsl:attribute name="keep-together.within-page">20</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="keep-with-previous.within-page">auto</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```